# how to use public ip4 in socket python

Tags: python, ipv4

MY code:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

server.bind(("47.29.209.94",4567))    #  my public ip
server.listen(5)
server.accept()
print("connected")
```

I got "OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address", but in case of ipv6 it works fine. only ipv4 gives this error. How to solve this error guys, I want to use public IPv4 address

Comment: You probably have a public IPv6 address but IPv4 is behind NAT. You have to listen on your local IPv4 address and forward the port on your router.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to assign it to your public ip address , you can just use

```
server.bind(("0.0.0.0",4567))
```

which will listen to all interfaces , and can accept public connection from internet if you use port forwarding properly